# Valgrind complet test my program

Tags: valgrind

is there any complete test valgrind? Any command that will test them all.

```
--start complet test ./myapp.exe
```

I have 3.3.1-Debian

Thank you.

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me *at all*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from your question [though i'm not able to find a proper "*question*" here] it is not very much clear what you want to ask.

- If you mean to say, you want to use all the available valgrind tools to be run in a single invocation, well, that's not possible. By default, the tool that is invoked with `valgrind` command is the `memcheck` tool for dynamic memory related error checking. You can use any of the available tools [cachegrind,  callgrind etc] in valgrind framework using `--tool=<toolname>` in different invocations.
- If you want to test for **ALL** the leaks in your code , (including `possibly lost` and `still reachable` ), you can use following option with `memcheck`

  - `--leak-check=full`
  - `--show-possibly-lost=yes`
  - `--leak-resolution=high`

For more detailed information, please see [this page](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual.html). Happy Debugging.